# How can I make my Unity panels and window controls look like this?

Tags: 16.04, unity, desktop-environments, customization, cinnamon

I'm a Linux noob, currently playing with Ubuntu on VirtualBox, using this site a lot to help me and am looking to take the next step and dual boot. Hopefully the Linux gods on this website can help me yet again!

I am struggling to set my desktop up to how I would like it to look. I like parts of Unity but also want parts to be 'Windowsey'. I've tried making my ideal desktop on Cinnamon but couldn't get the applets to work how I would like.

Here is a picture I made up of how I want it to look:

[image: The intended appearance of the graphical interface (see text below for a detailed description).]

So it uses the top and side bar of Unity (which I actually quite like), I also really like the Unity search feature. I would then want a 'Windowsey' taskbar at the bottom with its own menu, and also I want the window controls to be on the right side.

Hopefully you guys can help me (I'm assuming the answer is staring me in the face).

EDIT: I'm not against the idea of using a different desktop environment if that can get similar results.

Comment: Since it sounds like you want the Unity launcher and dash, I've changed your question title to ask how to get the panels and window controls look the way you want them in Unity. However, you should feel free to edit your post again (or even roll back my edit completely, if you feel the need), if it doesn't express what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you just want a start menu in the lower left with the bar on the bottom? Or do you actually want to keep the additional top bar?

Comment: @EliahKagen Thanks, hopefully your re wording of the title will get the correct message accross

Comment: @FatalMerlin I want a windows/cinnamon like bar at the bottom, and the top bar to be there for me to add other things to. For example I would want ram and cpu usage at the top, and current programs on the bottom

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK this can't be done. A good alternative would be cinnamon or XFCE or KDE with two bars and a dock on the left. KDE can have a full screen unity like launcher on its top bar and a standard menu on the bottom one, on the same desktop. Also MATE is very customizable but I have not used it.

Comment: @MarkKirby thanks, I will try KDE and see if I can get something going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of messing around I have pretty much what I was after with Gnome 3.

[Here is what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD3tt.jpg)

I installed Gnome 3, knowing that its search feature was similar (enough) to the unity one for what I wanted. I then downloaded the Dash to Dock extension

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

Dock at the side with the all apps button at the top which does the searching.
Then I downloaded a task bar extension (its not letting me share the link sorry), to give me a task bar at the bottom.

All that is left to do is to tinker with it some more, make it look more how I want, and see if I can get a more windowsey start menu from the bottom taskbar.

Thanks a lot for the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Months later I have come back to this with another answer. It is possible to install and run task bars from other desktop environments including; Xfce (which is what I currently use in conjunction with Gnome 3) Mate panel and Cinnamon.

Simply install them 'sudo apt install {insert panel name here}' then set it as one of the starting applications.